# sumtwo problem in leetcode: Hi , I am new to Leetcode and I am trying to solve first problem

Tags: python, list

PROBLEM : Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]. I am getting error as " IndexError: list index out of range" what is wrong with my code?

following is my code:

```
def sumtwo():
    arr = [1,2,5,3,4]
    l = []
    target = 6
    
    for i in arr[0:-1]:
        for k in arr[i+1:]:
            if arr[i] + arr[k] == target:
                l.append([i,k])
            else:
                continue
                
    return l

sumtwo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first trial is not bad at all. But, here we'd want to solve the problem with O(N) time complexity. This'll pass:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        indices = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in indices:
                return indices[target - num], index
            indices[num] = index
```

My guess is that, what you're currently planning to implement is similar to:

```
def sumtwo():
    arr = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
    l = []
    target = 6

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for k in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] + arr[k] == target:
                l.append([i, k])
            else:
                continue

    return l


print(sumtwo())
```

However, that does not return the desired output.

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.
- For [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt), we'd like to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).
- Brute force algorithms usually get accepted for [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions. For [medium](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Medium) and [hard](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Hard) questions, about 90% of the time, brute force algorithms fail mostly with [Time Limit Exceeded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) (TLE) and less with Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE) errors. For interviews, optimal and efficient algorithms are usually desired, especially if the question would be an [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) level.

---

### Happy Coding! ˆ_ˆ